# Manipulation of directories java/python

Tags: java, python, file

Let's suppose I have one directory A, and this directory has several subdirectories, and each subdirectory has varied amount of files. What I want to do is: insert all files into a single directory in the order they are in subdirectories in java, python or c

Comment: Update your question with more specific example. like your input and your desired result.

Comment: Also, it's probably in your best interests to just pick one of the languages; each individual one will lend its own pros and cons to the problem. Just doing a blanket "whichever language you want" is likely to be a bit broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to accomplish, but maybe this will help.

If you have this directory structure:

```
A
A/bar
A/bar/x
A/bar/y
A/bar/z
A/foo
A/foo/a
A/foo/b
A/foo/c
```

And you want to copy all of the files into a flat directory such as:

```
B
B/a
B/b
B/c
B/x
B/y
B/z
```

You can accomplish this in Python fairly easily:

```
import os
import os.path
import shutil

os.mkdir('B') # Assuming `B` does not already exist.

for root, _dirs, files in os.walk('A'):
    for name in files:
        source_path = os.path.join(root, name)
        dest_path = os.path.join('B', name)
        shutil.copyfile(source_path, dest_path)
```